# How to rename a file in a directory in grails

Tags: java, file, grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.1.1. I want to change a file name on a event. That's why I have attempt some. I just want to rename the file. But my process is not working. Can anyone please help me on this please?!!! Here is my attempt below in controller >>>

```
String previousFileName = inceptionInstance.fileName
        StringBuffer newFileName = new StringBuffer(previousFileName);
        int start = 0;
        int end = previousFileName.indexOf("_");
        newFileName.replace(start, end, params.firmName);

        File f = new File(grailsApplication.config.files.location.toString() + File.separatorChar +   previousFileName);
        f.renameTo( new File( grailsApplication.config.files.location.toString() + File.separatorChar + newFileName) )
```

Comment: What's not working about this? What error are you getting?

Comment: no error , just not renaming the file under directory

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Just take a look at this ...

```
new File(grailsApplication.config.files.location.toString() + File.separatorChar +   previousFileName).renameTo(new File(grailsApplication.config.files.location.toString() + File.separatorChar +   newFileName))
```